# Finding the element in a column corresponding to index(min/max element) of another column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have two columns COl A and COl B.I want to get the element in COl A corresponding to the index of the minimum Element in Col B.
I have tried to use Address() and Match() function but no success so far.Can any one  tell me what will be the correct formula for this.
Rgds,
Softy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is your data, with the letter a being in cell A4.

```
Col A   Col B
a   hi
b   there
c   my
d   name
e   is
```

To look up the position of, say the 'c', in column A, the formula is like this:

PUT THIS IN CELL A2

```
=MATCH("c",A4:A8)
```

Gives the result of '3', meaning that it found the letter C in the 3rd position down.

To then lookup that in column B, the formula is like this:

```
=INDEX($B$4:$B$8,A2)
```

The index, looks in the range and picks the third one down, which is 'my'

You could combine them as well:

```
INDEX($B$4:$B$8,MATCH("c",A4:A8))
```

Comment: You can modify the match formula to put a min() fx inside it to find the min value and lookup based on that.

Comment: MATCH would need a zero as third argument...so you can use this formula to get softy's required result `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MIN(B:B),B:B,0))`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DBMIN()` function. You'll need to look up the documentation for it, though.